# GetEnumerator: return or yield return

Tags: c#, iterator

My class implements IEnumerable. And these two ways to code GetEnumerator method can be compiled:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return Database[id].GetEnumerator();
}
```

and

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
   return Database[DatabaseId].GetEnumerator();
}
```

where Database[id] is List. Is any difference between these implementations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that compiles is because you are being unclear what the enumerable is. If you make it generic it becomes more obvious:

```
public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Database[id].GetEnumerator();
}
```

vs

```
public IEnumerator<IEnumerator<Foo>> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return Database[id].GetEnumerator();
}
```

Your `yield return` version is not yielding the result: it is yielding *the iterator* - it is an iterator-of-iterators, an enumerator-of-enumerators. And not in a good way. Basically, "don't do that".